# How to convert string dd-mmm-yyyy to date in sql/snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting date in the format `Sat Dec 31 07:56:31 UTC 2020` in snowflake in string format.
Ideally I would like to convert it to Timestamp. But if not, I can work with converting dd-mmm-yyyy to date format in sql.

I tried using substr to extract dd, mmm , yyyy from the string, and want to convert it to timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(REPLACE('Sat Dec 31 07:56:31 UTC 2022','UTC',''), 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS YYYY')

This worked for me.